# Excel.Range Copy() works very slowly

Tags: c#, office-interop, excel-interop

I'm building a report in which try to copy the previous row cell styles in the following

```
for (int i = 0; i < DataSource.Length; i++)
{
    int rowNumber = i + s;
    Excel.Range RngToCopy = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + rowNumber.ToString(), "K" + rowNumber.ToString());
    Excel.Range r = ObjWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + (rowNumber + 1).ToString(), "K" + (rowNumber + 1).ToString());
    RngToCopy.Copy(Type.Missing);
    r.Insert(Excel.XlInsertShiftDirection.xlShiftDown);
    r.PasteSpecial(Excel.XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats,
                   Excel.XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1] = i + 1;
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 2] = DataSource[i].TerminalName;
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 3] = DataSource[i].Type;
    ObjWorkSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 4] = DataSource[i].Requisite;

}
```

everything works but very long
How can I speed this up?

Comment: Define "very slowly". It might be slow only on your machine. How do you compare performace?

Comment: if I just build reports he built 2 seconds. if I use up styles - Reports are 15 seconds. 105 rows in the report. it should not be. so I'm looking for a faster method of copying

Comment: RngToCopy.Copy(Type.Missing);I think all because of this method

Answer (score 0):

I think you manually copy you will be improved.

```
Object[] origData = origRange.Value2;
destRange.Value2 = origData;
```

That should be WAY faster.