# Copy Excel cell formats to range very slow

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I use the following code to copy one Excel row format (template row) to a range of rows filled with data, but it gets incredibly slow with more rows (current test with about 33000 lines as target range).

The line slowing down the whole process is `Range.PasteSpecial(...);`, without the line it would take a few seconds, with it it takes minutes.

```
range = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[9, 1], worksheet.Cells[9, 44]];
range.Copy();
range = worksheet.Range[worksheet.Cells[10, 1], worksheet.Cells[iRow + 8, 44]];
range.PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteFormats, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
excel.CutCopyMode = 0;
```

Is there a different approach to retreive a range format and set it to another range, possibly faster (also within seconds)?

Comment: is interop excel? or something else?

Comment: may be relavant to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029822/excel-range-copy-works-very-slowly/33178551#33178551

Comment: @DanielTshuva yes, it's interop excel.

Comment: @VáclavStruhár i will try using this, thanks

Comment: @VáclavStruhár did not work, the Value2 property is only a different value, no format/style info.

Answer (score 0):

Interop is inherently slow because of the multiple layers, but the trick with speeding up Format operations is to do them in as large a block as possible - do the format copy once and then apply it using PasteSpecial to as large a range of cells as possible.

Comment: i think this is what i did, but is there a way to only copy the cell format as you implied?

Comment: Would be good to see more of your code: I assumed iRow was a loop variable. Have you turned off screen updating?

Comment: iRow was used in an earlier loop, yes. in that context it's the last row of the  target range for format copying.

yes, that took away probably a few seconds, the whole process still takes half an hour though.